# Is it possible to mock (and return a value) from an IDataReader using Rhino Mocks?

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I'm using RhinoMocks, and according to [this post](http://www.lazycoder.com/weblog/2008/12/12/mocking-idatareader-using-rhinomocks-35/) it should be possible to mock an IDataReader.

However, I'm using VB instead of C#. My stub is written like so:

```
reader.Stub(Sub(fnord) fnord("ColumnName")).Return(expectedId)
```

But it tells me that "expression is not a method".

Is there any way to do this in VB, or do I have to use C# if I want to mock an IDataReader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
reader.Stub(Function(fnord) fnord("ColumnName")).Return(expectedId)
```

As you are writing the lambda for a function instead of a subroutine, you need to use `Function` instead of `Sub`.

I haven't touched VB in a few years, so apologies if this does not help.